# Dispose and JProgress Bar issues on JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, swingworker, jprogressbar

I have some issues with a JDialog component.

1- The DialogWait extends JDialog and define an indeterminate JProgressBar. It seems that randomly the progress bar doesn't appear, and the Dialog seems in crash (no action performed, no possibility to close it if I press on X).
See:
 [image]

2- Again, some other times, the dialog doesn't disappear when I call dispose(). It seems to be stucked just before the dispose() method (i verified with some prints on console). The effect is that the application doesn't go on and the don't go out from the swingworker.

```
   DialogWait dialogWindow = new DialogWait(); 
     SwingWorker<Void, Void> swingWorker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

                while(newTimeSet != _record.getCurrentTimeMs()) {
                    _record.stepForward();

                    if(valuesMap.get(varName).equals(value))
                        valuesMap.put(varName, value);
                }

                dialogWindow.close();
                return null;
            }
        };

        swingWorker.execute();          
        dialogWindow.makeWait("Loading");
```

DialogWait class:

```
public class DialogWait extends JDialog{

    private JDialog dialog;
    private JProgressBar progressBar;


    public void makeWait(String msg) {

        dialog = new JDialog(Gui.getMainFrame(), msg, JDialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);

        progressBar = new JProgressBar();
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Wait..."), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        dialog.add(panel);
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setPreferredSize(Gui.getMainFrame().getSize());
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(Gui.getMainFrame());
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

 public void close() {
           dialog.dispose();       
   }
```

I am confused because the issues don't seem to occur in specific situations.

Comment: Remove this: `dialog.setPreferredSize(Gui.getMainFrame().getSize());`  You have already called `dialog.pack()`, which sets the dialog’s size to the size it should be.

Comment: that's right. Unfortunately didn't solve any of the issues.

Comment: Swing methods may only be called in the AWT Event Dispatch Thread.  The code you’ve shown doesn’t make clear whether it’s running in that thread.  I can, however, see that you are calling `dialog.close();` from the wrong thread;  override the SwingWorker’s [done()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#done%28%29) method, and move `dialog.close();` to that method.